# Sun JDK 6 installation in Ubuntu fails with "ELF: not found"

Tags: ubuntu, java

I was following this [doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) and installing Sun JDK 6 in my Ubuntu server v11.

```
root@li339-83:~# wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
root@li339-83:~# chmod u+x jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
root@li339-83:~# ./jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
Unpacking...
Checksumming...
Extracting...
./install.sfx.331: 1:ELF: not found
./install.sfx.331: 2: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
Failed to extract the files.  Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of
the Installation Instructions on the download page for more information.
```

I tried to find the solution for "ELF: not found" but couldn't find a solution. Any idea on how to solve this ELF issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to install Oracle JDK (and other softwares) on Ubuntu is probably to use standard Debian tools such as apt-get or synaptic.
To do so, you will have to add the WebUpd8 team PPA (more details [here](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java)).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, and I am not sure if I am right or not,  if you are on a 64-bit system and try to install something that is strictly 32-bit , such as a 32-bit JDK, then you need to download and install the 32-bit elf libraries into your Ubuntu linux system.  This is probably because, those libraries are expected to be unnecessary if you are on a 64-bit system.  The 32-bit elf libs (from the 32-bit version of Ubuntu) are still available though if you download them manually.  I ran into an issue similar to this trying to install a 32-bit WebSphere demo on a 64-bit CentOS system about a year ago.